# How do I make a ajax-loaded UL sortable in a JQuery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to load a UL in the background and then present it in a dialog for sorting, but I'm new to JQuery/JQuery UI and clearly having trouble with Google. This is as far as I've got:

```
$(document).on('click','a.priority', function(){
    // Get the URL of the link
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    // Tell the page to expect JS instead
    href = href + "/ajax";
    // Get the page content
    $.get(href, function(data){
        // Initialise a dialog for the content
        var my_dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .dialog({
                 autoOpen: false
                ,open: function (event, ui) {
                    // Add the result of the GET (a UL) as the dialog's content
                    my_dialog.html(data);
                    // Make it sortable, how?
                    my_dialog.sortable().disableSelection();
                    // Set the dialog title (this will be dynamic later, and we might need to call a single dialog that gets remangled rather than creating one every time)
                    my_dialog.dialog("option","title","Change priority");
                }
            });
        // Show the dialog
        wsd_dialog.dialog('open');
    });
    // Don't follow the link
    return false;
});
```

This will grab the content (a UL of items that need sorting) and present it in a dialog - but the UL appears as a single 'sortable' element.

How do I make the LI children of the UL sortable rather than the UL itself?

Have a feeling this is a silly question, I must be missing something in the docs.

Comment: Looks like you're calling `sortable()` on the dialog. You need to select the list items within the dialog and call `sortable()` on those.

Comment: I should have been clearer - that's what I'm asking how to do. I tried putting a ('ul') selector in the "my_dialog.sortable().disableSelection();" after 'my_dialog' - but maybe it should be "my_dialog.html.some-other-thing.('ul').sortable()".

Comment: Try `my_dialog.find('ul').sortable();`

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you :)

Do you want to post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

"wsd_dialog.sortable({ items: "li" })" also works - I must have missed that when looking at the documentation the first time - but your method is better because there could be other content in the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're calling `sortable()` on the dialog. You need to select the list items within the dialog and call `sortable()` on those:

```
my_dialog.find('ul').sortable();
```